# AJAX POST to MVC Controller showing 302 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I want to do AJAX POST in my MVC View. I've written the following:

**Script Code in View**

```
$('#media-search').click(function () {
    var data = { key: $('#search-query').val() };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Builder/Search',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.builder').empty();
                alert("Key Passed Successfully!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller Code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string key)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Simple", new { key=key });
}
```

But on AJAX POST I am getting the **302 found Error**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The '302' response code is a redirect. Your controller action explicitly returns a `RedirectToAction`, which simply returns a 302. Since this redirect instruction is consumed by your AJAX call and not directly by your browser, if you want your browser to be redirected, you will need to do the following:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/Builder/Search',
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: function (data) {
          if (data.redirect) {
              window.location.href = data.redirect;
          }
          $('.builder').empty();
          alert("Key Passed Successfully!!!");
     }
});
```

If not, you'll need to return something more meaningful than a redirect instruction from your controller.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to another Page.
I just want to return some data from that Controller's action in MVC.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be returning a `RedirectToAction`, which simply returns a 302 redirect to another URL.

Comment: then what I should do to just return the Json values to the view?

Comment: Yes, look into `JsonResult` - http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx