# asp.net mvc3 302 found error on $.get call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is a 302 found error code in asp.net mvc3 ? I am trying to do a simple jquery $.get call to get current time stamp from the server.

following is the code :

javascript

```
var url = '/Utility/GetTimeStamp';
$.get(url, function(data){  $("#curr_time").val(data); });
```

c# mvc

```
public ActionResult GetTimeStamp()
{
   string time_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
   return Content(time_stamp);
}
```

Comment: 302 means data is in cache

Comment: how do i get rid of this error ?

Comment: did that, still the same ..

Comment: yup. i did this too var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Comment: isn't 302 a redirect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX POST to MVC Controller showing 302 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118956/ajax-post-to-mvc-controller-showing-302-error)

Comment: What is the name of the controller?

Answer (score 1):

if the name of the contoller is UTILITY.. and currently you are there

try this code

javascript

```
   var url = 'GetTimeStamp';
    $.post(url
     ,{}
     , function(data)
        { 
           $("#curr_time").val(data); 
        });
```

C# MVC

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetTimeStamp()
{
   string time_stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
   return Json(time_stamp);
}
```

its returning a json result.

Answer (score 0):

you mean 304?
1、add a random number or datatime to you ajax request（$.get） param
2、use $.ajax({cache:false})
3、set no cache in server side code like
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like this in your web.config?

```
<location path="assets">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I was having this issue and for all un-authenticated requests were being re-directed to the sign in page.   try pasting the ajax url in a new browser window and see what you get.