# 302 found in ajax request.didnt hit to the post action .How to solve this

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a select box in my view.an ajax request is passed through its change.But found an 302 error.My code is below.It doesn't hit to the controller action.In network header status code is 302 found shown.Why this error occur and how to solve this. Here is code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.memberType', function () {       
    var memberTypeID = $(".memberType").val();         
    if (memberTypeID != null) {
        alert(memberTypeID)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetDetailsMember", "Approvemembership")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ memberTypeIDJson: memberTypeID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data)

                if (data.IsStaff ){
                    $('.staffDetail').show();
                    $('.studentDetail').hide();
                }
                else if (data.IsStudent) {

                    $('.studentDetail').show();
                    $('.staffDetail').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('.staffDetail').hide();
                    $('.studentDetail').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
})

   public string GetDetailsMember(string memberTypeIDJson)
   {         
       SchooberrySchoolEntities db=new SchooberrySchoolEntities();
       var memberType = db.LibraryMemberTypes.Where(p => p.MemberTypeId == memberTypeIDJson).Select(p =>new{IsStudent=p.IsStudent,IsStaff=p.IsStaff}).FirstOrDefault();

       if (memberType != null)
       {
           return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(memberType);
       }
       else
       {
           return "false";
       }          
    }
```

Comment: Check if you have [HttpPost] attribute added to your method in the controller.
Also you can check your route config, if something is overriden there

Comment: yes.added.But the breakpoint is not hitted to the controller.

Comment: Please update your question with your rendered code for that script part

Comment: there is some exception at your controller method that you are calling , you  can add   `<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>` to your web config.

Comment: Change your url  url: "@Url.Action("GetDetailsMember", "Approvemembership")",
to
 url: "/Approvemembership/GetDetailsMember"

it will work

Comment: Thankyou.It's worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX POST to MVC Controller showing 302 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118956/ajax-post-to-mvc-controller-showing-302-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your url url: "@Url.Action("GetDetailsMember", "Approvemembership")", to url: "/Approvemembership/GetDetailsMember" it will work.

Please check this answer [AJAX POST to MVC Controller showing 302 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118956/ajax-post-to-mvc-controller-showing-302-error)